# Add constant updatable column for a view in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have this view :

```
Create View View1 
AS 
Select F1,F2,0 As F3
From TB1

GO 

Update View1 Set F3=1
```

These commands raise this error :

> Update or insert of view or function 'view1' failed because it contains a derived or constant field.

Is there any solution for updating "F3" field?

Thank you

Comment: You need to add that column to a table.

Comment: Actually I Don't have permission to add a column to referenced Table.

Comment: Why you want to UPDATE a VIEW? I think you must change your way and make a new view or use that view in another way ;).

Comment: It is perfectly legal to update through a view, but you're not updating the view, you're updating the underlying tables.

Comment: @ZohrehTavakoli: I have updated my answer below to include a solution that allows you to UPDATE directly on the view, but you need an extra table to store the value of the F3 column.

Answer (score 5):

The only way to change the value of a constant column in a view, is to alter the view itself. It does not make sense to run UPDATE statements on a constant or calculated column on a view, as the value is not stored physically in any table. Therefore, you have to do something like this:

```
ALTER VIEW View1 A
Select F1,F2,1 As F3
From TB1
```

Now, you could be tempted to put this code into a Stored Procedure. Unfortunately, this is not possible either, since [DDL statements are not allowed in Stored Procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716546/why-cant-sql-server-alter-a-view-in-a-stored-procedure). Another solution is therefore to store the value of column F3 in a separate table and change the view definition to bring the value into the view:

```
CREATE TABLE F3Column (
    Value AS int
)

go

INSERT F3Column VALUES (0)

go

CREATE VIEW View1 AS
select F1, F2, Value AS F3
from TB1, F3Column

go

-- This will allow you to change the value directly on the view:
UPDATE View1 SET F3 = 1
```

Just make sure that your F3Column-table always contains exactly 1 record. If it doesn't contain any records, View1 will always be empty. If it contains more than 1 record, View1 will give you duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

`F3` is not a column in any table, that's why you cannot update the value. Either you need to add it to your table or just display it as a new value in some conditions using `CASE`

```
CASE WHEN [condition goes here] THEN 1 END
```

Comment: Actually I need to make a new physical column on view. Is it possible?

Comment: No, such columns has to live in a table.

Comment: As @LasseV.Karlsen mentioned you cannot. But why do you want to update a non existed column? As I said in my answer you can just display it as another value in certain conditions

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a result that shows `1` as `F3` in your results like this:

```
SELECT F1, F2, 1 As F3
FROM View1
```

Or make a new view like this:

```
Create View View2 
AS 
Select F1, F2, 1 As F3
From TB1    
GO
```